# Access to logger within an ExceptionListener in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to log some informations with the logger service within an ExceptionListener class but I don't understand how to access / create a logger object...

Here is my piece of code :

```
class ExceptionListener
{

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        ...
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            // HTTP Exception (400, 401, 404, ...)
            $response = new JsonResponse(...)
        }
        ...
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

The listener works perfectly but in this case nothing is logged by default into the `dev.log` file (of course logging is enabled and functional).

I tried to had an `LoggerInterface` parameter to the `onKernelException` function  (autowiring ?) but without success.

Should I had some additional configuration in the `service.yaml` file ?

```
App\EventListener\ExceptionListener:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

Comment: Inject the logger into your listener.  Lots of examples out there.

Comment: Yes, I already try it, but I have an error : `Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException() must implement interface Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, string given, called in / ... /vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 212`

Comment: Inject it into your constructor.  Injection directly into a method only works for controller actions.

Comment: Yeah ! It works. Added a constructor with a `LoggerInterface`. I'm so stupid because I already use this method in an other part of my code. Thank you very much guys !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Autowiring being by default on SF4, you should be able to inject the LoggerInterface into your listener without further configuration, like so (then call $this->logger when desired) :

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
class ExceptionListener
{
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        ...
        $exception = $event->getException();
        if ($exception instanceof HttpExceptionInterface) {
            // HTTP Exception (400, 401, 404, ...)
            $response = new JsonResponse(...)
        }
        ...
        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I already try it, but I have an error : `Type error: Argument 2 passed to App\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException() must implement interface Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, string given, called in / ... /vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/EventDispatcher.php on line 212`

Comment: I think @David is still keeping LoggerInterface parameter in function onKernelException. This parameter must go to constructor (as in this answer) and onKernelException will have only one parameter.

Comment: Yeah ! It works. Added a constructor with a `LoggerInterface`. I'm so stupid because I already use this method in an other part of my code. Thank you very much guys !